# JSONP using .getJSON is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm trying out an exercise in Learning jQuery 4th edition by Karl Swedburg for Ajax, and more specifically JSONP.

My code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url='https://api.github.com/users/jquery/repos';
$.getJSON(url + '?callback=?',function(data){
  var content='';
  $.each(data,function(index,item){
    content +='<div class="userdata">';
    content +='<div class="username">'+item.id+'</div>';
    content +='<div class="username">'+item.name+'</div>';
    content +='<div class="userurl">'+item.url+'</div>';
    content +='</div>';
  });
  $('#dictionary').append(content);

});
});
```

I've checked the developer tools and my request is returning status 200

and an extract of the data returned from the request is as shown below

```
{
  "id": 5999890,
  "name": "2012-dev-summit",
  "full_name": "jquery/2012-dev-summit",
  //more stuff
}
```

I've checked and double checked my code and can't seem to figure out why is it returning undefined.

EDIT:Added what is appended

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

i get 6 undefined,which would equate to 2 iterations seeing as outputting 3 items per round, ie. id,name and url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below. You are getting the result in result.data object. Not in result object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url='https://api.github.com/users/jquery/repos';
$.getJSON(url + '?callback=?',function(result){
  var content='';
  var data = result.data;
  $.each(data,function(index,item){
    content +='<div class="userdata">';
    content +='<div class="username">'+item.id+'</div>';
    content +='<div class="username">'+item.name+'</div>';
    content +='<div class="userurl">'+item.url+'</div>';
    content +='</div>';
  });
  $('#dictionary').append(content);

});
```

});

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3fb9v/)

Comment: Your code works, but why exactly does it work? What do you mean by im getting the result in result.data.object and not result.object?

Comment: You are directly looping through the result from getJSON callback in your code(data). But the actual data lies inside data.data in your code, In my code inside result.data. So you need to loop through the result.data to access the result objects. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url='https://api.github.com/users/jquery/repos';
$.getJSON(url + '?callback',function(data){
  var content='';
  $.each(data,function(index,item){
    content +='<div class="userdata">';
    content +='<div class="username">'+item.id+'</div>';
    content +='<div class="username">'+item.name+'</div>';
    content +='<div class="userurl">'+item.url+'</div>';
    content +='</div>';
  });
  $('#dictionary').append(content);

});
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbNEC/5/)

Comment: Why does changing ?callback=? to ?callback make it work? From the docs, it says that the string has to contain callback=? for it to work, so why does it changing it make it work in this case?